# Declare const with typescript argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsc

Say we have:

```
const foo = [1,2,3].map(v => {

});
```

is there a way to do something like:

```
const foo = [1,2,3].map(const v => {
    v = 5; // does not compile
    return v + 3;
});
```

So far `const` works but not for arguments/parameters tmk. Note I am just trying to get the behavior of the final keyword in Java:

```
public void run(final String s){
   s = "bop"; // no
}
```

Comment: that's not how you use map, you need to return something ... anyway, either code will end up in an empty array, since you start with an empty array

Comment: that has nothing to do with the question, the question is just about using `const` in the arguments list so you can't overwrite it

Comment: oh, right ... `const v` in the argument - is that valid typescript to declare an argument as `const`? of course you can't change a `const` ... it's a `const` ... are  you sure it's not the fact that you put the `const` in `.map(const v` that causes the error? because that would be my guess

Comment: If that is indeed valid to put `const v` as the argument, then of course you can't change the value of `v` - its *incoming* value has been tagged as **constant** - == you can't change it ... and the first thing your code does is ..... *change it*

Comment: It doesn't compile because it's not valid TypeScript, not because `v` is constant. I think what OP is asking is if there is a way to declare `v` as constant so that the line `v = 5;` does not compile. There is no way to do that.

Comment: There isn't currently a way to mark a parameter as readonly/const.  Relevant [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18770) with links to more relevant issues.

Comment: all you have to do is use something like [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) ... when you put your code in there, the error is made obvious by the javascript that is output

Comment: yes that's great, but there might be a different syntax that I don't know about that accomplishes the same goal

Answer (score -4):

It would kinda defeat the purpose of `const` if you could, don't you think?  How about:

```
const foo = [1,2,3].map(const v => {
    const v1 = 5; // now it compiles
    return v1 + 3;
});
```

instead?

Comment: This is invalid TypeScript and you've completely missed the point of the question.